# Does Bokeh require a ColumnDataSource and a Hover tool for each graph you want to display?

Tags: python, bokeh

I am just starting with Bokeh, and so far I find it very straightforward (beside the fact that you can't use a list of strings for one of the axis, but that's a different issue).

I am making multiple graphs, and group them together in a tab; this is working but I did notice that

- You need a HoverTool for each graph, because if you use the same for multiple graphs, one works while the other does not
- You need a ColumnDataSource for each HoverTool; otherwise I get `????` when displaying data, if more than one hovertool is using the same ColumnDataSource

Is there a way to work around this? I am planning to make 8-10 graphs, which are all taking data from the same source (I use a list of lists; each one is a dataset); and I need already 8-10 exact lines to generate each figure, so adding extra code for each one, to get the HoverTool and ColumnDatSource would not be ideal.

The source for the tooltip is the same for all the graphs; it is a list of strings which I use as ID for each chemical reaction test; I thought it was just a matter of pointing the HoverTool tooltip funciton to the list, but it require a ColumnDataSource.

This is what I have so far:

```
list_reactions = ['a1b3', 'a1b4', 'a1b1', 'a2b3']
list_results1 = [0.22, 0.34, 0.44, 0.55]
list_results2 = [0.12, 0.24, 0.34, 0.45]
list_x_values = [1, 2, 3, 4]

source_test1 = ColumnDataSource( data=dict(
    reactions=list_reactions,
    x=list_x_values,
    y=list_results1,))

source_test2 = ColumnDataSource( data=dict(
    reactions=list_reactions,
    x=list_x_values,
    y=list_results2,))

hover1 = HoverTool(tooltips=[("reactions","@reactions")])

hover2 = HoverTool(tooltips=[("reactions","@reactions")])

test1 = figure(title="experiment1", tools=[hover1])
test2 = figure(title="experiment1", tools=[hover2])

test1.line(x, y, line_width=2)
test2.line(x, y, line_width=2)

test1.circle(x, y, size=8, source=source_test1)
test2.circle(x, y, size=8, source=source_test2)

tab1 = Panel(child=test1)
tab2 = Panel(child=test2)
tabs = Tabs(tabs=[tab1, tab2])

show tabs
```

Unless I create 2 hovertool and 2 sources, I can't get the popup to display the `reactions` when hovering. Lots of repetition when the only thing that change between the various charts, is the y values.